# css style not getting applied

Tags: css

I have a div for which I have a style defined as below:

```
 <div class="timeline-icon label" style="margin-top: 10%">
  <a class="red">Changes</a>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline-icon" style="margin-top: 15%">
   <a class="red">25</a>
 </div>
```

I have the corresponding classes in my css file:

```
.timeline .timeline-icon a{
  border: 5px solid #2d353c;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.2s linear 0s;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Now for the top div which contains the `Changes` text, I have added an extra class called `label` so that the div will be a rectangle and not a circle. I want all the properties from the `timeline-icon` but want to override the `border-radius` and `width`properties. How to add the selector? I am new to CSS.

Comment: `.timeline .timeline-icon.label a { border-radius: 0px; /*and your other properties*/ }`

Comment: Use "!important" css tag

Comment: @ddacot .. and what "!important" will do :P

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/

Don't use important, if you use css properly you won't need it.

And don't use inline css too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply append the two classes together as so:

```
.timeline .timeline-icon.label a{
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

You'll notice there is no space separating the `timeline-icon` and `label` classes, this is because we want the styles to apply to `a` elements whose parent has both classes present.

NB: It is also vital to ensure that the above style is placed AFTER your original style (the one you're trying to override). As it is in this case, the overriding style is more specific that its predecessor so it should apply regardless but its worth ensuring nonetheless.